# “Click” a javascript button with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use VBA to click the button: **search job posting**

[button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KHuv.png)

The html code:

```
                        <td><br> <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-small" value="Search"></td>
                        <td><br>-or - <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="orbisApp.buildForm({action:'displayAdvancedSearch'}).submit()"> Search Job Postings </a>
```

I was attempting to do it by something like:
**IE.document.Something.Click**

Much appreciation for someone who can help me to figure out the "something"!!!

Comment: I'd use querySelector() and querySelectorAll() http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/01/vba-webscraping-jquery-selectors.html

Answer (score 0):

There are probably better ways to identify a button, but when I was testing this stuff for fun a long time ago checking the onclick property was the only reliable way to identify a button on the site I was interfacing with. I'm assuming you know how to reference the browser window based off what you said. I included the Microsoft HTML Object Library to get the HTMLButtonElement type.

```
Dim htmlElements as Variant
Dim buttonElem As HTMLButtonElement

Set htmlElements = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("BUTTON")
For Each buttonElem In htmlElements
    If InStr(1, buttonElem.onclick, "orbisApp.buildForm({action:'displayAdvancedSearch'}).submit()") > 0 Then
        buttonElem.Click
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is simply use the form element to click the button. Your statement:

> IE.document.Something.Click

Is almost spot on.

Here's the code you want to use

```
IE.document.Forms(0).Submit
```